# How to change values of a vector according to the values of another vector ？

Tags: r

```
data1 <- data.frame(abb = c("ap","be","pi","straw","sun","straw","pen"), gdp = c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80))
data2 <- data.frame(abb = c("ap","be","pi","straw","sun"),
                    fullname = c("apple","bear","pine","strawberry","sunny"))
```

I want to replace `data1$abb` with `data2$fullname`.

I try to use the following code to realize it, but I get a warning message:

```
find1 <- paste(data2$abb, collapse = "|")
data1$abb[str_detect(data1$abb, find1)]<- data2$fullname
```

How can I realize it?

Comment: well if they are of same length then data1$abb <- data2$fullname will do, if not R will recycle. But can you try to post the data in English.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This may serve your purpose

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- data1 %>% left_join(data2) %>% 
  mutate(fullname = ifelse(is.na(fullname), abb, fullname)) %>%
  select(fullname, gdp) %>% select(abb = fullname, gdp)
```

Comment: nope. I just wanna  keep one vector named "abb" in data1.

Comment: @user14345711 if you can post expected output, it may better help in understanding your requirement.

Comment: @user14345711 I have edited the solution, you may please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
data1 %>%
  full_join(data2) %>%
  mutate(abb = coalesce(fullname, abb)) %>%
  select(-fullname)
```

which gives

```
         abb gdp
1      apple  20
2       bear  30
3       pine  40
4 strawberry  50
5      sunny  60
6 strawberry  70
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[data2, abb:= fullname, on = .(abb)]
```

-output

```
data1
#          abb gdp
#1:      apple  20
#2:       bear  30
#3:       pine  40
#4: strawberry  50
#5:      sunny  60
#6: strawberry  70
#7:        pen  80
```